# Error al liberar memoria con delete en un destructor c++

Tags: c++

estoy aprendiendo sobre c++ e intentando liberar memoria con el operador delete en el destructor del objeto obtengo un error, pero si hago lo hago en un metodo no obtengo ningun error, a que se debe eso? gracias de antemano, saludos

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class obj{
public:
    obj(int t);
    ~obj();
private:
    int *array;
};
obj::obj(int t){
    array = new int[t];
}
obj::~obj(){
    delete [] array;
}
int main()
{
    obj obj1(5);
    obj1.~obj();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si te sale error en algunos lugares si, y en otros no, o algunas veces si, y otras no y no hay un motivo aparente por lo que este sucediendo, lo mas probable es que este cayendo en comportamiento indefinido en algun punto en tu codigo. Hasta esa conclucion se puede llegar con la informacion que compartes. Si quieres una respuesta mas completa, seria bueno que compartieras un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Gracias por comentar, ya le agregue algo de codigo para ilustrar mejor lo que esta pasando, saludos.

Comment: Ahh, ya con el código es bastante claro. No tienes que llamar al destructor tu, este lo llamaran automáticamente cuando tu variable sale de su scope. Como lo llamas tu, y luego de llama automáticamente, tratas de borrar la memoria 2 veces, cayendo en comportamiento indefinido como te comente antes.

Answer (score 5):

Estás incurriendo en *comportamiento indefinido*; tu código puede funcionar ... o no. O hacerlo solo en luna llena.

Vamos a hacer un pequeño cambio para que lo veas con claridad:

```
obj::~obj(){
    std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    delete [] array;
}
```

Si lo ejecutamos ahora, obtenemos

> Destructor
> Destructor

¡ Estás llamando al destructor **2 veces** ! Y ahí tienes tu problema. En cada una de esas llamadas, se ejecuta `delete [] array;`. La primera vez, todo funciona bien, pero la segunda ... pues estás intentando liberar una memoria que **ya ha sido liberada con anterioridad**... y he ahí el *comportamiento indefinido* que decíamos al principio.

C++ **no recuerda** si un destructor ha sido llamado ya o no. Pero **si** garantiza que se llamará cuando tu variable deje de existir ... que en este caso concreto, es justo cuando llegas al `return`. Y en ese momento invocará al destructor ... otra vez.

En tu caso, basta con **no** llamar al destructor y todo funcionará perfecto:

```
obj::~obj(){
    std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    delete [] array;
}

int main()
{
    obj obj1(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Y ahora si, la salida es la esperada:

> Destructor

Comment: Graciass  ,error de novato xD

Answer (score 3):

Puedes obtener el mismo error con el siguiente código:

```
int main()
{
    int array = new int[5];

    delete[] array;
    delete[] array; // ¡Doble borrado!

    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, se está borrando `array` dos veces, tienes una solución rápida que consiste en asignar un valor nulo al puntero después de borrar la memoria a la que apunta:

```
int main()
{
    int array = new int[5];

    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr;
    delete[] array; // No pasa nada.

    return 0;
}
```

Invocar el operador de borrado sobre un puntero nulo es inocuo, tal y como especifica [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf) (traducción y resaltados míos):

> #### 7.6.2.9 Delete
>
> 7. Si el valor del operando de la expresión-`delete` **no es un puntero nulo**, entonces:
>
>    - Si la llamada de alojamiento de la expresión-`new` para el objeto a borrar no se omitió y el alojamiento no se extendió, la expresión-`delete` debe llamar a la función de desalojado [ … ].
>    - En caso contrario, si el alojado se extendió o se proveyó extendiendo el alojado de otra expresión-`new`, y la expresión-`delete` para cualquier otro valor de puntero producido por una expresión-`new` que tuviera almacenamiento proveido por la expresión-`new` extendida hubiera sido evaluada, la expresión-`delete` debe llamar la función de desalojado [ … ]
>    - **En caso contrario, la expresión-`delete` no llamará ninguna función de desalojado**.

Esto evita el problema del doble borrado pero ¿Por qué se está borrando dos veces?.

---

Se está borrando dos veces porque el destructor de la instancia `obj1` de `obj` se llama dos veces, la primera manualmente y la segunda automáticamente:

```
    int main()
    {
        obj obj1(5);
        obj1.~obj(); // Llamada manual al destructor de 'obj1'.
        return 0;
    }
// ^ <--- Llamada automática al destructor de 'obj1'.
```

Así que: no llames manualmente el destructor.